# Least upper-bound property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I started reading Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis, and I had a question about step number three in the construction of real numbers (Chapter 1, appendix)
This part of the construction says that the set P has the property of the least upper bound.

[image]

I have several questions:

1. Why there always exist $\alpha$ $\in$ A? I understand that $\alpha$ looks something like this: (-$\infty$, 0). For example, A(4, 5), B[5, $\infty$)
2. Why does it follow from all of the aforementioned in step 3 that the union of all sets $\alpha$ is the upper bound of set A?

Comment: I think that "least upper bound property" stands for "If the set of upper bounds is non-empty, then it has a minimum", so by hypothesis we freely obtain the fact that the set of upper bounds is not empty. If it is empty, then the set is not bounded and there is nothing to do.

Comment: You have assumed that $A$ is a *non-empty* subset of $R$.  That's why $\exists \alpha \in A$.  All elements $\alpha \in R$ are cuts, which means they are downward closed, so they can't look like $(4, 5)$ or like $[5, \infty]$.  Each $\alpha \in A$ is a cut of rational numbers, so the proof simply proves (a) the set $\gamma$ of all rationals in any $\alpha \in A$ is itself a cut, so it's an element of $R$, and (b) that particular cut $\gamma$ is the least upper bound of $A$. . . .

Comment: . . . .  It has to be an upper bound because it contains any possible cut in $A$. Any smaller $\beta$ would mean that $\gamma \setminus \beta \neq \varnothing$, so $\beta$ must omit some $q \in \alpha \in A$.  In other words, if $\beta \lt \gamma$ then $\beta$ wouldn't be an upper bound for $A$.  That means $\gamma$ is not just an upper bound for $A$, it's the smallest possible upper bound for $A$.

Comment: @RobertShore By definition of a cut: if there exists such a number q ∈ Q, less than p ∈ α, then q belongs to the cut. If I take a non-empty set A, bounded from below, let's say by the number -1, then -2 will not belong to this set, therefore it will not belong to any of its cuts, therefore there is not a single cut in the set A. What do I understand wrong?

Comment: $A$ is not itself a cut.  The elements of $A$ are cuts.  In other words, a cut is a subset of the rational numbers, but $A$ is a set of subsets of the rationals, which is to say that $A$ is a subset of $\mathscr P(\Bbb Q)$, whereas a cut is a subset of $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, there will always exist some cut $\alpha\in A$ because $A$ is defined to be a nonempty subset of $R$, and $R$, by definition, is the set containing every cut of $Q$, and is thus only cuts, so by definition, $A$ must contain at least 1 element, and those elements must all be cuts, so $\alpha$ will exist.

For your second question, the union of all the cuts contained in $A$, $\gamma$, must be the least upper bound of A because if you consider some element of $R$ that is an upper bound of $A$, $\beta$, by the definition of upper bounds and the ordering of $R$, every $\alpha \in A$ is a subset of $\beta$, and thus their union is also a subset of $\beta$, so $\gamma\subset\beta$, thus $\gamma\le\beta$, and $\gamma$ is less than an arbitrary upper bound of $A$, and thus every upper bound of $A$. Furthermore, because $\gamma$ is the union of all elements of $A$, every $\alpha\in A$ is a subset of $\gamma$ by the definition of a union. Thus, $\alpha\le\gamma$, therefore $\gamma$ is an upper bound of $A$, and is less than every other upper bound of $A$, and so is the least upper bound of $A$, by definition.

A bit verbose, but I tried to not skip any steps. Hope this helps!